# Why is my trie root pointer shown some value while it has already been deleted & assigned NULL?

Tags: c++, pointers, trie

There are two scenarios :

1. when I tried to delete whole trie it deleted perfectly as root = 0x0 or NULL
2. but when I tried to delete entries one by one and after deletion final entry while checking whether root was NULL or not, it gave me root = not NULL

Now this is my whole trie deletion code -

```
void del(Node *&cur) {
    if (!cur) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (cur->next[i])
            del(curr, cur->next[i]);
    delete cur;
    cur = NULL;
}
```

Usage -
`del(root)`

From Debugging window -
[image: Root Node Screenshot]

Now my delete specific node code -

```
void remove(Node *&curr) {
    if (curr->parent) {
        Node *temp = curr->parent;
        if (curr->wordCount > 1) {
            curr->wordCount--;
        }
        else {
            temp->next[curr->id] = NULL;
            delete curr;
            curr = NULL;
        }
        remove(temp);
    }
    else {
        curr->wordCount--;
        if (curr->wordCount == 0) {
            delete curr;
            curr = NULL;
        }
    }
}

void findRemoveItem(char *str) {
    Lookup var = search(str);
    if (var.isAvailable) {
        var.lookedupNode->isLeaf = false;
        remove(var.lookedupNode);
    }
    else {
        printf("Not a word\n");
    }
}
```

Usage -
`findRemoveItem(arr[7]) //arr -> string array`

from debugging window -
[image: trie root info]

In the 1st image, root node was deleted completely.
But in the 2nd image, it looked like kind of deleted but not completely.
Why is that?

[Whole code](https://ideone.com/hsUr8C)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By trie do you mean tree?

Comment: @Tom No, I mean Trie Data Structure. But under the hood which is a tree.
[link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you writing c code with c++ features (new/delete)?

Comment: Suggestion: Make initialize member variables in the member initializer list. Your constructor can be made into this: `Node() : isLeaf(false), next{}, parent(nullptr), wordCount(0), id(-1) {}` - no `for` loop needed.

Comment: Suggestion 2: Your `del()` function checks if the pointer is `nullptr` both upon entry and before calling itself for child nodes. Skip the check before calling itself for child nodes: `void del(Node*& cur) {
    if(!cur) return;
    for(auto& child : cur->next) del(child);
    delete cur;
    cur = nullptr;
}`

Comment: the recursive method do not have access to the `root` variable, but still deletes what it points to

Comment: @sp2danny `del(Node*&)`  - it takes the pointer by reference.

Comment: Seeing references and pointers together is never a good sign. You should be using references *or* pointers, not pointers to references or references to pointers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo When the last item gets deleted, so does the node `root` points to. This happens at `findRemoveItem(arr[7])`

Comment: @sp2danny yes I knew that cause when `del()` is called  after `findRemoveItem(arr[7])` execution got access violation error for being tried to delete root node which had no allocation then.So question stands,  `findRemoveItem(arr[7])` got root node deleted but could't make it to NULL. Why?

Comment: @sp2danny And `del()` is also recursive. It can access root & make it to NULL while `findRemoveItem(arr[7])` can't

Comment: @SPD is using c++ features (new/delete) a bad practice? If so I will keep mind in future. Its just preference to me. Feels good to use new/delete rather than malloc/calloc/free.

Comment: @tt817263 it's certainly your choice. My point is since you're already using C++ features, why not writing proper C++ code? i.e. write an OO trie structure, use std::array rather than c array, std::string rather than c string etc .. The code would be much more readable and you don't have to worry about the cumbersome c string operations. Personally I'd be happy to help you with C++ code, but wouldn't bother with C. Since yours is mostly written in C, you may want to tag it with "C" to get the attention of right people.

Comment: @tt817263 `del()` can make root null, because it has direct access to it, you are sending it in as a parameter. The `findRemoveItem` does not have access to that variable, but still finds the node it points to, via the parent pointer, and deletes that.  At that point, `root` points to a node that no longer exists.

Comment: And the solution is to not delete the root node. This is the part that's in the else section in `remove`, where you test if `wordCount` is zero. This also makes it possible to continue inserting, even if you first removed all content from the trie